# Getting the time of batch interval

Tags: spark-streaming

I am writing a spark streaming application I need to get the time of my current batch interval..how to do this?..I wanted to know also how the time is tuned..it is tuned based on the time of machine in the driver of the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you need to specify the batch interval of your Spark Streaming app, when you create `StreamingContext`

**for example:**

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
```

In this above code, every 2 seconds, your spark streaming job pulls the data from input source ( kafka, file etc...)